# Quick-start sample app for C# doesn't work. Ideas?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-plus, google-signin, google-api-dotnet-client

Need help running this sample Google+ API Quickstart w/ C# app please, using VS2015 and following directions from here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/csharp

I have so far:

1. Enabled the Google API and played with it in OAuth2.0 Playground.
2. Set http://localhost:4567 as an Authorized JavaScript origin.
3. Cloned the "googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp" repository in Github found here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp
4. Changed the client ID and secret to what I was given from the Google developer's website.
5. Tried to build but ran into NuGet build errors, so I deleted the NuGet completely and had all the target references re-downloaded and then rebuilt the project. Everything compiled.
6. Ran the project. Here I can clearly see the Google+ button but when I click on it, nothing happens!  Also made sure pop-ups work in my browser.  I've tried Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Any idea why clicking the button does nothing? There is a pop-up that I am expecting to see as the guide suggests but it never appears. I feel like I followed the directions well...

My code is up in a public Github repository here (client secret is reset): https://github.com/ForeverCodingAndLearning/googleplus-quickstart-csharp

Please help or comment with suggestions as to where a beginner with this would go wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Did you analyse your request (error, network traffic) by using the F12 tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That project on GitHub hasn't been touched on GitHub in 2 years.
2. He is using a version of the .Net client library from 3 years ago he included it in the project.
3. The project targets .Net framework 4.0 which is no technically longer supported by the Google .Net client library.

Any one of those would explain why its not working

I will try and make an upgraded version of that tutorial asap.  My  [Google Plus api sample code](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%2B%20API)

Comment: Awesome, let me know when it's up, thank you!  I figured that might be the reason but, you know, since it was online and available even with [outdated] documentation from Google pointing to it I figured I could somehow get it to work...

Comment: My asp and mvc are very rusty.  May take a little while.  It will end up on my blog.

Comment: I finally understand after 8 hours time waste... have you done your new solution in your blog ?